# Setting axis' style without CSS

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I am building  a line chart with d3 
 and am trying to make my ticks a grey, while my axes and tick labels will be a dark grey. How can I style this inline in d3, without using CSS? I can't quite seem to get it right. Thanks in advance!

This is how I build my x and y axes:

```
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
  .scale(x)
  .ticks((width + 2) / (height + 2))
  .tickSize(-height)
  .tickPadding(10)
  .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b %d, %H:%M:%S"))


var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y)
  .scale(y)
  .ticks(5)
  .tickSize(-(width - 100))
  .tickPadding(10)
```

How I append them:

```
var gX = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis--x")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis)
var gY = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis--y")
  .call(yAxis)
```

I was trying to put:

```
.style("stroke", "#c3c3c3")
```

On my y axis like this:

```
var gY = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis--y")
  .call(yAxis).style("stroke", "#c3c3c3")
```

But that only changes the color of my tick labels and not the lines... where might I be going wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do this...

```
svg.append("g").call(yAxis).style("stroke", "#c3c3c3")
```

... you are effectively setting the `stroke` of the `<g>` element that contains the paths, lines and texts. Obviously, you expect this to set the style of all those elements.

However, the D3 axis generator automatically sets the styles of the `<line>` and `<path>` elements. Let's have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis/blob/da24fba38bb895a3a7ed9f3fdddda1a545eec97e/src/axis.js#L63):

```
path = path.merge(path.enter().insert("path", ".tick")
    .attr("class", "domain")
    .attr("stroke", "currentColor"));

line = line.merge(tickEnter.append("line")
    .attr("stroke", "currentColor")
    .attr(x + "2", k * tickSizeInner));
```

Therefore, those styles set by the axis generator will override the style you set to the group (in the above code, currentColor is just the [CSS currentColor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#currentColor_keyword)).

Let's see it in this demo, using red for the `stroke`:

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg");
const g = svg.append("g");
const axis = d3.axisBottom(d3.scaleLinear().range([10, 290]));
g.call(axis).style("stroke", "red")
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

As you can see, we applied the style to the group, but only the text elements inherited it (and they look ugly because that is the `stroke`, not the `fill` style).

**Solution**:

Select the elements you want and apply the style to them.

For instance, selecting the lines and paths:

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg");
const g = svg.append("g");
const axis = d3.axisBottom(d3.scaleLinear().range([10, 290]));
g.call(axis).selectAll("line,path").style("stroke", "red")
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

---

**PS**: Since the new release of D3 uses `currentColor`, you can paint everything just using the `color` property! Have a look:

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg");
const g = svg.append("g");
const axis = d3.axisBottom(d3.scaleLinear().range([10, 290]));
g.call(axis).style("color", "red")
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! It helped me understand so much that I needed to know!